# Big endian and small endian confusion

Tags: encoding, cryptography, endianness

I have seen two definitions for big endian/small endian which cause my confusion.

The first definition is the classic one related to machine:

Big-endian systems store the most significant byte of a word in the smallest address and the least significant byte is stored in the largest address (also see Most significant bit). Little-endian systems, in contrast, store the least significant byte in the smallest address.

This makes perfect sense and this is the definition of big/small endian in my whole life until I came across various discussions related to cryptography:

1. book "Cryptography for Developers" By Tom St Denis says, "the OS2IP function converts the octet string to integer by loading the octet strings in big endian fashion. That is, the first byte is the most significant."
2. https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10824/what-does-an-rsa-signature-look-like/10826#10826
   In the accepted answer of this question, it says, "The padded value is then interpreted as an integer x, by decoding it with the big-endian convention."

Apparently, these two crypto discussions does not involve anything related to the machine architecture. What is their definition of big-endian fashion/convention?

Comment: Big/little endian are about representing the numbers with bytes (which byte comes first). Any architecture has to make choice about the representation, just in their terms 'comes first' means 'has smallest address'. Besides computer architecture, there are also data formats, network protocols, cryptography algorithms etc. Or do I understand the question wrong?

Comment: But in the context of these crypto discussions, there is no assumptions of machine or address. How do they determine the address based on that? Another way of saying my confusion is how can you decode the value in big endian convention while your data is stored on x86 machine? (see case 2)

Comment: @bereal, In case 2 above, the person does not seem to care about how you store in on the machine. Say you have char buf[2] = {0xA, 0xB}. The decoder will interpret 0xA as the most significant byte regardless whether its address is higher than 0xB or not. That is my understanding. But I am not sure if this is exactly the definition of big-endian convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Big and little endian are just conventions about representing numbers with bytes. In big endian, the most significant byte comes first, in the little endian it's the other way around. Different architectures, data formats, algorithms and networking protocols may adopt different strategies.

Moreover, good programs will not depend on the endianness of the architecture, for example, to read a number from an array you could write something like:

```
int read_bit_endian_16(unsigned char *data) {
    return (data[0] << 8) + data[1];
}
```

or using functions like `ntohs()` and friends.

In Python it's:

```
struct.unpack('>h', data)
```

Binary data formats are good example of when endianness is important, if you expect them to be cross-platform. If you write data in a low-endian platform, you want to be able to read it in a big-endian one. That's why any decent format specify those things explicitly, and portable programs take into account chances of being compiled/run in different architectures. Other example would be multibyte character encodings like UTF16-LE and UTF16-BE.

You can find a more detailed explanation [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-endianc/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But in the example you gave, I dont think endianness of the machine has any effect. In fact, I haven't seen a scenario where the endianness of the machine can cause a problem. Could you give a example on that? I will take your answer after that.

Comment: @dannycrane updated, please let know if that answers your question.

Comment: The link is quite helpful!